# Rand() isn't displaying random number, please help me understand what's wrong :)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random

So I am new to C++ and learning all alone... until now everything went fine, but i am learning how to use rand() and the result does bother me a little...

So my goal is to generate a random number for the HP of a player at the beginning of a game. To be fair, I set up a minimal HP of 50 points and I want to create a random number with 50 being the minimal and 200 the maximum.

```
int HP = 50 + rand() %200;

cout << HP;
```

Now, the problem is:

The program always give me the same `int`.
To check the result i created a new project and only displayed the `rand()` number with the same values, and I got the same result -> `91`. 
this mean, I would say `int HP = 91;` would be exactly the same.

Practice and trial being the key to learn (I think) I tried the same `rand()` values on 5 new projects, always the same number...

Comment: ***The program always give me the same "int".*** Did you forget to seed the random number generator?

Answer (score 2):

> std::srand() seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by rand(). If rand() is used before any calls to srand(), rand() behaves as if it was seeded with srand(1).
>
> Each time rand() is seeded with srand(), it must produce the same sequence of values on successive calls.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

Therefore, what you're seeing is (awkardly) exactly what `rand` is supposed to do.  The easy fix is to call `std::srand(std::time(nullptr));` so that each time the program runs, it starts with a different seed.

The more advanced fix is to study [The awesome C++ standard randum number library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

```
std::default_random_engine e1(r());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(50, 250);
int HP = uniform_dist(e1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` isn't really the best random number generator, but if you're going to use it you need to seed it with the `srand` function as follows:

`srand(time(0));`